# Counting the number of restricted Integer partitions

Tags: math, integer, dynamic-programming

## Original problem:

Let ***N*** be a positive integer (actually, N <= 2000) and **P** - set of all possible partitions of the ***N***, where [image] with [image] and [image]. Let ***A*** be the number of partitions [image]. Find the ***A***.

Input: ***N***. Output: ***A*** - the number of partitions [image].

## What have I tried:

I think that this problem can be solved by dynamic-based algorithm. Let **p(n,a,b)** be the function, which returns the number of partitons of **n** using only numbers **a**. . .**b**. Then we can compute the ***A*** with the code like:

```cpp
int Ans = 2; // the 1+1+...+1=N & N=N partitions
for(int a = 2; a <= N/2; a += 1){ //a - from 2 to N/2
    int b = a*2-1;
    Ans += p[N][a][b]; // add all partitions using a..b to Answer
    if(a < (a-1)*2-1){              // if a < previous b [ (a-1)*2-1 ]
        Ans -= p[N][a][(a-1)*2-1];  // then we counted number of partitions
    }                               // using numbers a..prev_b twice.
}
```

Next I tried to find the dynamic algorithm computing **p(n,a,b)** for any integer a <= b <= n. [This paper (.pdf)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/062c/f83ec47bdcffd24ec213e78880a34a8de287.pdf) provides the folowing algorithm:
[image], were **I(n<=b)** = 1 if n<=b and =0 otherwise.

## Question(s):

1. How should I realize the algorithm from the paper? I'm new at d-p problems and as I can see, this problem has 3 dimensions (n,a & b), which is quite tricky for me.
2. How actually that algorithm works? I know how work the algorithms for computing **p(n,0,b)** or **p(n,a,n)**, but a little explanation for **p(n,a,b)** will be very helpful.
3. Does original problem have simpler solution? I'm quite sure that there's another clean solution, but I didn't found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated all A(1)-A(600) in 23 seconds with memoization approach (top-down dynamic programming). 3D table requires 1.7 GB of memory.
For reference:  `A[50] = 278, A(200)=465202, A(600)=38860513616`

N=2000 requires too large table for 32-bit environment, and map approach worked too slow.

I can make 2D table with reasonable size, but this approach requires table zeroing at every iteration of external loop - slow again.
`A(1000) = 107292471486730 in 131 sec`. And I think that long arithmetic might be needed for larger values to avoid Int64 overflow.

Comment: Yes, A053263 seems like the right sequence. Thanks for your reply!